# File descriptor for ioctl call to make a controlling terminal

Tags: linux, process, file-descriptor, ioctl, pty

On linux to be able to control lifetime of processes forked off of my main process I'm making the main process be the session and group leader by calling `setsid()`. Then it looks like I need to have the main process make a controlling terminal for the process group, and then, once the main process terminates, all other processes in the process group will receive a SIGHUP. I tried calling `open()` for a regular file on the filesystem, but `ioctl()` refuses to accept this fd with 'Inappropriate file descriptor'. Is `posix_openpt()` what I should be using instead? The man page says that it'll create a pseudo-terminal and return a file descriptor for it. Do I even need an `ioctl(fd, TIOCSCTTY, 0)` call after `posix_openpt()`, or not using `O_NOCTTY` is all I really need? Thanks!

Comment: I tried *not* calling ioctl() for the fd and parsing the stat file I see ctty device id still being 0. So, when in man pages for open() it says 'O_NOCTTY', does this mean that I need to make an ioctl() call always and then as I make the call regardless of whether or not 'O_NOCCTTY' was used, the terminal will become the controlling terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I even need an ioctl(fd, TIOCSCTTY, 0) call after posix_openpt(), or not using O_NOCTTY is all I really need?

I just tried on Ubuntu 18.04.5:

If you don't do that and the controlling process is closed, the `systemd` process becomes the new controlling process of the child process and the child process does not receive `SIGHUP`.

I'm not sure if this behavior is the same for other Linux distributions, too.

> Is posix_openpt() what I should be using instead?

Try the following code:

```
int master, tty;

master = posix_openpty(O_RDWR);
grantpt(master);
unlockpt(master);
tty = open(ptsname(master), O_RDWR);
ioctl(tty, TIOCSCTTY, 0);
```

This must be done in the same process that called `setsid()`.

Note: As soon as you completely close the `master` file, the processes will receive a `SIGHUP`.

("Completely" means: When you close all copies created by `dup()` or by creating a child process inheriting the handle.)

If you really want to use the pseudo-TTY, you should not inherit the `master` handle to child processes (or `close()` the handle in a child process. However, in your case you only want to use the pseudo-TTY as "workaround", so this is not that important.

Comment: What's a "controlling process"?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica In fact, I'm talking about the "parent process" returned by `getppid()`. However, the `SIGHUP` section on the `man`page of `signal (7)` is talking about a "controlling process". I'm not sure, but the "parent process" and the "controlling process" seem to be the same thing. But maybe the process leader is meant...

Comment: Thanks @MartinRosenau. Both master and slave fds worked for me for lifetime management. I'm still unsure whether using one is better than the other, or if there's a better way altogether to implement what I wanted (I originally suspected that there was a higher-level utility to control lifetime of a tree of procesess, but I'm not finding anything...)